# Multithreading in python while connecting SFTP server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, pysftp

I wrote a python script to connect to SFTP server. Code takes its server credentials from a text file.
Text file format
IP,USERNAME,PASSWORD
IP2,USERNAME2,PASSWORD2
IP3,USERNAME3,PASSWORD3

Now the problem with this code is if PASSWORD2 is wrong then it will raise authentication error which is understandable but due to this error the loop breaks and process stops and it does not process line 3 of text file. Multithreading can solve the problem as if in multithreading if 1 thread fails rest keep on running.

But i dont know multithreading in python.please help me to modify this code to multithreading.

```
import os
import pysftp
import csv
import socket
from stat import S_IMODE, S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
import time
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import os.path
import shutil
import fileinput
import lock

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

try:
    with open("text.txt", "r") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)
            IP=row[0]
            myUsername=row[1]
            myPassword=row[2]
            txtfile=row[3]
            remotepath=row[4]
            localpath=row[5]
            print(IP)
            print(myUsername)
            print(myPassword)
            print(txtfile)
            print(remotepath)
            print(localpath)

            with pysftp.Connection(host=IP, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
                r = str(socket.gethostbyaddr(IP))
                print("connection successful with " + r)
except:
    print("failed")
```

Comment: If one thread fails, because of the wrong password, how will other threads keep running?

Comment: i dont know much about multithreading, i need modification such that if there are 10 IP's in a the file. so it creates 10 threads one for each IP and if incase 'thread 2' fails due to authentication error other threads keep on running.          beginner in python

Answer (score 1):

The requirement you have does not require multi threading.

All you have to do is place the `with` block within a try catch

```
for row in csv_reader
 ...
    try:        
       with pysftp.Connection(host=IP, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, 
         cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:

         <your logic>
    except pysftp.SSHException:
       print("Failed to connect")
```

Comment: is it possible by multithreading.   I need to use that due to project requirements

Comment: pycharm shows unresolved reference for "log" in last line.    what additional module do i need t import?

Comment: I have just added the log variable for your reference. you can just move the give code to a new method and submit it to a thread for execution. You will still have to have the try catch block though for a clean exit.

Comment: Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html for more info, and regarding logging https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html kindly look at the above link